# Difference between yum update and using rpm to install updates

Tags: redhat, yum, update

I am trying to figure out why exactly this isn't working correctly. Currently there is no way supported by yum to set a milestone in time (install all packages up to point in time *T*). To get around this for our QA purposes, we would like to use the yum-downloadonly plugin. We are able to use the plugin in tandem with *yum update* to pull down all packages that would be included in the update.

However, when we try to run `rpm -ivh *.rpm` where all of the files have been downloaded, there are tons of errors about dependencies. If you force it, you end up getting tons of errors on the next boot. Trying to do a yum localinstall produces similar problems.

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm not quite getting? Is there any way to preserve the order to install as yum would do? It's not like I'm missing packages - downloadonly pulls down everything a normal update would, including all dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running `yum -y update --downloadonly`, instead of `rpm -ivh *.rpm`, try `yum localupdate *.rpm`.

Comment: Fantastic, that seems to work like a charm! Thank you!